# Run every file in a folder and print fail ratio with Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to run every file in a folder and print "Success" or "Access Denied" and jump to the next file. But as soon as the script finds a file without permissions just stops instead printing "Access Denied" Can anyone help me with this?

PS: Is there a way to calculate ratio % of denied?

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\VM\Desktop> python script2.py
Success
Success
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VM\Desktop\script2.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.startfile(file)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied: 'file3.exe'
```

My code

```
import glob, os, time
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\VM\Desktop")
for file in glob.glob("*.exe"):
   try:
     os.startfile(file)
     time.sleep(1)
     print('Success')
   except ImportError:
     print('Access Denied')
```

Comment: What do you mean "just stops"? As in it prints Access Denied once and then exits the program? What exit code is printed?

Comment: Isn't `ImportError`, use `except PermissionError`.

Comment: Pretty certain @Trock 's solution will work for you

Comment: @AngusB The script print "Success" two times, then reaches a file without permission and shows a PermissionError, it didn't print. It should print "Access Denied" or "Fail" and keep running, jumping to the next files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to catch access denied, then your except statement should be like this:

```
except PermissionError:
   print('Access Denied')
```

Currently you are catching `ImportError`, which is a different error.

Regarding to the % of denied access files, you can just count the number of errors and the total, and then calculate the percentage. Something like this:

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\VM\Desktop")
_total, _errors = 0, 0
for file in glob.glob("*.exe"):
   _total += 1
   try:
     os.startfile(file)
     time.sleep(1)
     print('Success')
   except PermissionError:
     _errors += 1
     print('Access Denied')

print('error ratio:', _errors * 100. / _total)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thanks! Just added a missing "s" to "_error"